# Create from a data frame a df with binary values depending on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, logic

I have a data frame such as ;

```
   Groups   Value
    G1  NA
    G1  NA
    G1  NA
    G1  23
    G2  NA
    G2  NA
    G2  NA
    G2  NA
    G2  NA
    G2  NA
    G3  34
    G3  21
    G4  NA
    G4  NA
    G5  NA
    G5  45
```

and I'm looking for a code in R in order o get another data frame with binary values (1 for at least one Value in the group was a >=1) and (0 for Groups containing only NA values)

and get a new datagram such as:

```
G1  G2  G3  G4  G5
1   0   1   0   1
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use base R `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Value > 1~Groups, df1, any, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = na.pass)

#  Groups Value > 1
#1     G1      TRUE
#2     G2     FALSE
#3     G3      TRUE
#4     G4     FALSE
#5     G5      TRUE
```

If you need `1/0` values instead of `TRUE/FALSE` you could do

```
aggregate(Value~Groups, df1, function(x) 
           +(any(x > 1, na.rm = TRUE)), na.action = na.pass)

#  Groups Value
#1     G1     1
#2     G2     0
#3     G3     1
#4     G4     0
#5     G5     1
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do with `table` from `base R`.  Get the 'Value' column as a logical vector (`!is.na`), and find the frequency table with 'Groups', check whether the frequency is greater than 0, convert the logical vector to binary with `as.integer` or `+`

```
+(table(df1$Groups, !is.na(df1$Value))[,2] > 0)
# G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 
# 1  0  1  0  1
```

---

Or using `rowsum` from `base R`

```
rowsum(+!is.na(df1$Value), df1$Groups)
```

NOTE: Both the above methods are `base R` - No packages used

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Groups) %>%
  summarise_all(list(~ as.integer(sum(!is.na(.)) > 0)))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  Groups Value
#   <chr>  <int>
#1 G1         1
#2 G2         0
#3 G3         1
#4 G4         0
#5 G5         1
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, +(sum(!is.na(Value)) > 0), Groups]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Groups = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", 
"G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G3", "G3", "G4", "G4", "G5", "G5"), 
    Value = c(NA, NA, NA, 23L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 34L, 21L, 
    NA, NA, NA, 45L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, you can also do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Groups) %>%
 summarise(Value = as.integer(any(!is.na(Value))))

  Groups Value
  <chr>  <int>
1 G1         1
2 G2         0
3 G3         1
4 G4         0
5 G5         1
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Groups) %>%
 summarise(Value = as.integer(max(Value, na.rm = TRUE) > 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

by using looping condition we can extract the same

## data

```
data <- data.frame (Groups =rep(c("G1","G2"), each = 4),  Value = c(NA,NA,NA,23,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

## Loop

```
for (i in unique(data$Groups)){
  data$new_value[data$Groups==i] <- ifelse(sum(data$Value[data$Groups==i],na.rm = T)>1,1,0)
}


data1 <- unique(data[,c(1,3)])

Groups new_value
  G1         1
  G2         0
```